# is it correct to use "Netlify CMS" as cms for an e-commerce store?

Tags: e-commerce, netlify-cms

I'm new to JAMstack development, so this question arose. I found only one example of using Netlify CMS for e-commerce store: https://www.fullstackrocket.com/products/gatsby-ecommerce-netlify-cms

Answer (score 1):

Netlify CMS is great for managing and editing content that is stored in your git repository alongside your code as yaml, toml, json, or markdown files.

If it's a good choice for your usecase depends how you want to build your e-commerce store:

- If you build your site and online store from scratch with a site
  generator (like gatsby, nextjs, hugo, jekyll...) and want to store
  your product information in your git repo, Netlify CMS could be a
  good choice.
- If you use a site generator but manage your products in a proprietary
  e-commerce platform like Shopify, you could use Netlify CMS for
  managing other pages on your website or your blog

I checked Fullstack Rocket [here](https://www.fullstackrocket.com/blog) and [here](https://www.indiehackers.com/product/fullstack-rocket), there are no updates on their blog since April 2020, so I would ask if their products are up to date.